# Java remove focusPainted on DefaultMutableTreenNode in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, uimanager, defaultmutabletreenode

Is it possible to remove the *dots border* for `DefaultMutableTreenNode` in `JTree`?

For `JButton` I use:

```
JButton btn;
btn.setFocusPainted(false);
```

But I cannot find an equivalent for `DefaultMutableTreenNode`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is exactly what you are trying to achieve, but try this before you instantiate any swing components:

```
// For the border around the icon
UIManager.put("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon", false);
// Dashed border
UIManager.put("Tree.drawDashedFocusIndicator", false);
```

Comment: Hi Fry, see my update. If it does not work, then please give more details of what you are trying to achieve (with pictures maybe). `DefaultMutableTreeNode`does not draw anything, [DefaultTreeCellRender](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html) does (unless you are using a custom renderer).

Comment: As far as I can tell my [paint](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.java#DefaultTreeCellRenderer.paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) and [paintFocus](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.java#DefaultTreeCellRenderer.paintFocus%28java.awt.Graphics%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.awt.Color%29) implementation these are the two underline properties that controls focus drawing.

Comment: Work perfectly, only with the second `UIManager.put("Tree.drawDashedFocusIndicator", false);`

Comment: Hi Fry, I appreciate your attempt to organize the answer and my later edit, but I have roll backed your proposed changes and added comments to clear what each property does. They both control different aspects of what `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` draws on focus, and since readers of this question may be looking to tweak the focus behavior in different ways, I don't want anyone thinking that `Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon` does not work (actually, to totally disable the focus indication I think that both properties must be set to `false`).